# Hadoop node not showing the correct IP address

Tags: java, hadoop, ambari

I have installed my project on two machines and am now having a problem.

The IP of the node is not correct (its the loopback IP) and the heart beat is lost which I think this because of IP error:

[image]

Comment: 10.43.6.31   localhost  localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.43.6.55  client
10.43.6.55  client.hadoop.com
10.43.6.31  client3
10.43.6.31  client3.hadoop.com
10.43.6.13  fnode
10.43.6.13  fnode.hadoop.com
these are the contents of my host file client 3 is the machine with problem and i have removed the 127.0.0.1 from local host but nothing new

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it with graphical interface but I guess you should check /etc/hosts file to see whether the name is correctly linked to the IP address.